# What's the difference between a square and hexagonal Visit Pass in Singapore?

Tags: visas, passport-stamps, singapore

I frequently visit Singapore on short business trips, and have usually received a rounded rectangular (for brevity, "square") Visit Pass stamp.  However, on my last visit, the officer first stamped a square stamp, cursed, crossed it out and stamped in a hexagonal one instead:

[image]

**What, if anything, does the shape mean?** As far as I can tell the text of the two stamps is completely identical.  The officer said nothing to explain and my stays don't look like visa runs etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I hadn't realized this when I started asking the question, but while processing the photo I spotted the difference: the square stamp says **thirty days**, while the hexagonal one says **ninety days**.

Per Wikipedia my nationality entitles me to 90 days, so while the correction this time was right, previous square stamps of 30 days appear to have been in error!

Comment: Maybe you said something different to the officer this time about how long you intended to stay?

Comment: @davidbak Last time I stayed 2 days, this time 3.